# Error en condicional con Python - Value Error

Tags: python, condiciones

Soy nuevo en el mundo de Python y tengo un error que me está trayendo loco, ya que no sé donde está el error. Estoy haciendo un condicional que me diga el IMC del jugador en función del resultado de la operación matemática para obtenerlo y no encuentro el modo de que se ejecute el código. Sospecho que el problema está relacionado con los paréntesis, pero no soy capaz de averiguarlo, ya que además obtengo el ValueError [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con este tema? ¡Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Comment: No debe pegarse código (ni mensajes de error) como imagen, sino como texto. Y de todas formas tu imagen ha dejado fuera la parte más importante, el mensaje de error :-)

Comment: Uy, discúlpame, soy nuevo por aquí. Muchas gracias por echarle un ojo a la pregunta aún así, voy a borrarla y la reformulo adecuadamente

Comment: no hace falta que la borres, Edita la pregunta, incluso para el trabajo que hiciste era mas facil hacer print de pantalla y pegar la imagen que sacar una foto, descargar y subirla

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero, para ver mejor el código, que no sea foto porfa.

Y en el tema errores, no puedes hacer un condicional con if de un dataframe. Si quieres filtrar puedes hacerlo con .loc[] y después con el mismo loc lo asignas automáticamente. La solución sería la siguiente:

```
raw_data.loc[(raw_data["IMC"] < 18.5), "clasificacion_oms"] = "Delgado"
raw_data.loc[(raw_data["IMC"] >= 18.5), "clasificacion_oms"] = "Normal"
raw_data.loc[(raw_data["IMC"] >= 25), "clasificacion_oms"] = "Sobrepeso"
raw_data.loc[(raw_data["IMC"] > 30), "clasificacion_oms"] = "Obeso"
```

Con esto debería irte, en el .loc[] haces la comprobación (entre paréntesis), separado por coma y poniendo el nombre de la columna, y asignando el valor deseado. Los datos que no estén dentro de la condición tendrán valor nan.

#### Sintaxis

```
dataframe.loc[(condicion), "columna a asignar"] = "valor"
```